# Why does await is not working in case of constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

Dart version: 2.8.0

I'm getting this: Instance of `'Future<String>'` even though I'm using await.

See the code:
from loading.dart (this is first page when app launch)

```
 void setUpWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime worldTime = await WorldTime(location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png', url: 'Asia/Kolkata');
    pri(worldTime.getTime());

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUpWorldTime();
  }
```

world_time.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

class WorldTime {
  String location;
  String time;
  String flag;
  String url;

  WorldTime({this.location, this.flag, this.url});

  Future<String> getTime() async {
    print('called getTime()');
    Response response = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url');
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    String dateTime = data['datetime'];
    String offSet = data['utc_offset'].toString().substring(1, 3);
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offSet)));
    time = now.toString();

    return Future.value(time);
  }
}
```

Right now, I'm following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lCQhwo8WT4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=28

In above tutorial it is working because that time dart 1.0 was new

The problem in my code is this statement  `pri(worldTime.getTime());` is executing immediately, before completing API!

Also, please teach me that how to get value, which I tried to return like this:  `return Future.value(time);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor may only return an instance of the class it creates (`WorldTime`). Constructors cannot be asynchronouse because they would have to return `Future<WorldTime>` which is not supported.

In your case you should just create and instance of `WorldTime`:

```dart
WorldTime worldTime = WorldTime(location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png', url: 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

And then call asynchronous method `getTime` on it:

```dart
print(await worldTime.getTime());
```

Comment: yes, it's working but you not told, that how I'll get time in this loading activity

Comment: String temp = await worldTime.getTime();
    setState(() {
      time = temp;
      pri(time);
    });
  }

Comment: I tried this also: void setUpWorldTime() {
    WorldTime worldTime =
        WorldTime(location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png', url: 'Asia/Kolkata');
    setState(() async {
      time = await worldTime.getTime();
      pri(time);
    });
  }

Comment: Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843230/how-stick-to-with-adapter-position-while-its-scrolling-in-android/